# Разбивка многомерного массива по переменным

Tags: php, массивы, база-данных

Подключаюсь к базе данных сайта и вывожу результат в виде ассоциативного массива:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostDB, $userDB, $passwordDB, $database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    /* очищаем результат, чтобы переменная не хранила данные */
    $result->free();
}
/* закрытие соединения к БД */
$mysqli->close();
```

В результате на экран выводится:

```
Array ( [day] => Понедельник [active] => 1 [start_time] => 09:30 [end_time] => 18:58 ) 
Array ( [day] => Вторник [active] => 1 [start_time] => 09:30 [end_time] => 18:58 ) 
Array ( [day] => Среда [active] => 1 [start_time] => 09:30 [end_time] => 18:58 )
```

Как мне записать каждую строку вывода в отдельные ассоциативные массивы `$monday, $tuesday, $wednesday` и т.д.?

Answer (score 0):

Общая идея такая:

```
$a = 'b'; 
$$a = 'b-value'; // $$a - это обращение к переменной, чье имя содержится в $a
                 // т.е. в данном случае $$a эквивалентно $b
echo $b; // выведет "b-value"
```

Соответственно, в твоем случае

```
$($row[$day]) = $row; // для понедельника это эквивалентно $monday = ...
```

PS не проверял, допустим ли именно такой синтаксис, если нет - можно через промежуточную переменную:

```
$day = $row[$day];
$$day = $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostDB, $userDB, $passwordDB, $database);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table";

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
        /* извлечение ассоциативного массива */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $res[$row['day']]['active'] = $row['active'];
            $res[$row['day']]['start_time'] = $row['start_time'];
            $res[$row['day']]['end_time'] = $row['end_time'];
        }
        /* очищаем результат, чтобы переменная не хранила данные */
        $result->free();
    }
    /* закрытие соединения к БД */
    $mysqli->close();

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем за ответы, решил вопрос так (может кому пригодится):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostDB, $userDB, $passwordDB, $database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

/* переменные для хранения информации о днях недели */
$monday;
$tuesday;
$wednesday;
$thursday;
$friday;
$saturday;
$sunday;

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* записываем значения в переменные */
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; ++$i) {
        $row = $result -> fetch_assoc();
        if ($i == 0) {
            $monday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 1) {
            $tuesday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 2) {
            $wednesday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 3) {
            $thursday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 4) {
            $friday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 5) {
            $saturday = $row;
        }
        if ($i == 6) {
            $sunday = $row;
        }
    }

    /* очищаем результат, чтобы переменная не хранила данные */
    $result->free();
}

/* закрытие соединения */
$mysqli->close();
```